# Returning flipped image to its original view

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I have flipped image using the code below during occuring of an event.
now i want to again return image to its original view on happening of another event.
here is code i used to flip image.

```
CompositeTransform n = new CompositeTransform();
n.ScaleX = -1;
image.RenderTransform = n;
```

Comment: would you not just run the code again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
(image.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform).ScaleX = 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

In your case, use this line of code;

```
image.RenderTransform = System.Windows.Media.Transform.Identity
```

Comment: I am missing a namespace for your answer. can you please say it.

Comment: edited in - it may not exist in silverlight, if that is what you are using.

Comment: He's building a Windows Store app, not Silverlight.

Comment: @Gusdor because he's using the Windows 8 Runtime, not WPF (nor Silverlight). System.Windows.Media.Transform.Identity doesn't exist in that environment.